# Less than query with text field

Tags: sql, ms-access

Trying to find a number value in a text field

What is the syntax for finding values less than 10 in Microsoft access when the field is set to short text field?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the field data to numeric type in criteria (the field in table remains unchanged). Assuming field has only numeric characters and never Null, like:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE Val(field) < 10;`

If field can be Null, gets complicated because number conversion functions will error on Null.

Comment: Thanks but i have to keep it as Text.

Comment: The field itself is unchanged. Conversion of data takes place only in the filter criteria.

Comment: If answer resolves issue, please mark accepted. Upvotes are nice as well.